# How to autmatically excute r script with package by task scheduler?

Tags: r, automation, r-package

I wonder how to run an R script automatically with a package file with a task scheduler. I try to do that many times, but my script do make file.

If you guys know that, could you introduce how to execute an R script with a package?

I am trying to describe my issue with the below pictures.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you have selected the script you want to run, select the schedule. After that click on "Create Job", and then finally click on "Done". The file will run as per the schedule you've selected.